Interfacing 3.3V MCU with VCO: Op-Amp Gain and Offset Advice?
I'm working on controlling a VCO with my MCU, and I'm facing some challenges with voltage levels.
MCU Supply: 3.3V
VCO Supply: 11.5V
VCO Vtune range: 0.5V to 19V
I believe I need a non-inverting op-amp circuit with a gain of approximately 5.74. I’ve simulated this circuit using an AD820, but I'm unsure how to offset the output voltage to start at 0.5V.
How would you address this problem? Is it necessary to use three separate DC-DC converters to achieve the required voltages, or is there a more efficient solution?

I would not bother offsetting the output voltage, just apply a gain.
If you have a DAC with 0-3.3V out you would need a gain of at least 5.75.
Perhaps you use DC-DC with +24V output and regulate it down for the 11.5V VCO supply  (assuming the current draw is only a few mA you could use a linear regulator such as AMS1117-ADJ and a couple of resistors), and use it directly for the op-amp supply.
Something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

So your nominal tuning range is 0.5 to 19V which will require an input of nominally 83.4mV to 3.255V. You lose a few % of the resolution by going beyond the bounds but that means that the resistor tolerances and supply tolerances are not as important.
If you're looking for a stable and spectrally "clean" VCO output, pay attention to the sources of noise and drift- as shown, the VCO output frequency is directly proportional to the 3.3V supply voltage, so if it is noisy, your output signal will be affected. Noise on the op-amp supply should mostly be rejected by the op-amp, depending on the op-amp PSRR at the frequencies in the noise. The tolerance and stability of the resistors and the op-amp offset voltage and offset voltage drift will have effects.
